# How to access a function using an object which is stored inside a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object

I have created a class which has an object named entity inside it. The objects has a set of attributes and functions inside. 
In a different python file, I have created a dictionary of entity objects. The key is "id" (which is a variable used while creating the object) and the value is the object itself.
I want to know how can I access the functions of the entity objects which are stored in the dictionary?

The code for creating the entity:

```
class Entity:
def __init__(self, id, name):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.employee=dict()
    self.department=dict()
```

The functions I want to access inside the entity:

```
def add_employee(self, employee):
    self.employee.update({employee.get_emp_code(): employee})
```

The code for employee:

```
class Employee:
def __init__(self, entity_id, code,desc):
    self.entity_id = entity_id
    self.code = code
    self.desc=desc
    self.department=dict()
```

In another python file where I created the dictionary of entity objects

```
entities = cur.fetchall()
entity_dictresult= dict()
for row in entities:
    obj= Entity(id,name)
    entity_dictresult.update({obj.get_id:obj})
    return entity_dictresult
```

The function where I pass the dictresult as argument:

```
def get_all_employees( entity_dictresult):
    for row in query_result:
        obj=Employee(entity_id, employee_code, description)
        dictresult.update({obj.get_entity_id: obj})
```

Now, I want to call the `add_employee` function from the entity object in the `get_all_employees` function. But I have passed a dictionary of objects instead of object itself.

I want to know how to access the a function of an object which is stored inside a dictionary.

Comment: Where did you do the method for `obj.get_id`? This doesn't look valid since I see no `@property` tags. Also why is there no `()` in  `def get_all_employees:`

Comment: What happens when you try now?  What is your error?  It will make it faster for fix if we know exactly where the error is occurring so far rather than have to try to track through 4 chunks of disparate code.

Comment: Add the definition of your `Employee` class

Comment: Please ignore syntactical errors. This is just a very abstract example of my project. I want to access the add_employee function of the entity object using the dictionary